# How to pass a html tag in the value of select input in React js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to map values in the input field of a select tag but for some reason it gives me `[Object object]`. When I am not passing another tag in the return of the map statement, the output is coming fine. But I guess there is some other way of using html tags in the select value attribute.
The react hook used is:

```
                const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([])
```

And the return statement is:

```
                <label className="filter-label" for="country" multiple>Filter By Category</label>
                            <select id="country" name="country" className="search-input" 
                            onChange={e => setCategories([...categories, e.target.value])} 
                            value={categories.map(category => <ChipList key={category} 
                            data= {category} />)}
                            >
                                <option>{categories.length < 1 ? 
                                "Select category" : 
                                categories.map(category => <ChipList key={category} data={category} 
                                />)}</option>
                                <option value="australia1">Select category1</option>
                                <option value="australia2">Select category2</option>
                                <option value="australia3">Select category3</option>
                            </select>
```

In short how to write something like `value={<p>Hello</p>}` in the value attribute of select input without getting [Object object]

Answer (score 0):

do u want that on UI inside select it should be shown as

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

or just `Hello` ?

Comment: I want to display Hello. But the value attribute is not accepting any html tag or any other component